# constexpr std::optional possible implementation

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, c++17

I'm trying to implement `std::optional` with `constexpr` support as a practice. The usage will be something like:

```
constexpr optional<int> x(123);
int arr[*x];
```

When trying to implement this I got this one problem that I haven't been able to solve: Inside an `optional<T>` object, I use a `std::aligned_storage_t<sizeof (T), alignof (T)>` object to store the value, and use placement new in `optional<T>`'s constructor to construct value into the storage. But placement new cannot be used inside a `constexpr` constructor:

```
constexpr optional(const T& value)
    noexcept(std::is_nothrow_copy_constructible<T>::value)
    : ...
{
    new (ptr_to_storage) T(value);  // this breaks `constexpr`
}
```

How else can I implement this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use a union.

Check out how Andrzej does it:

https://github.com/akrzemi1/Optional/blob/master/optional.hpp#L282

```
template <class T>
union storage_t
{
    unsigned char dummy_;
    T value_;

    constexpr storage_t( trivial_init_t ) noexcept : dummy_() {};

    template <class... Args>
    constexpr storage_t( Args&&... args ) : value_(constexpr_forward<Args>(args)...) {}

    ~storage_t() = default;
};


template <class T>
struct optional_base
{
    bool init_;
    storage_t<T> storage_;

    constexpr optional_base() noexcept : init_(false), storage_(trivial_init) {};

    explicit constexpr optional_base(const T& v) : init_(true), storage_(v) {}

    explicit constexpr optional_base(T&& v) : init_(true), storage_(constexpr_move(v)) {}

    template <class... Args> explicit optional_base(in_place_t, Args&&... args)
        : init_(true), storage_(constexpr_forward<Args>(args)...) {}

    template <class U, class... Args, TR2_OPTIONAL_REQUIRES(is_constructible<T, std::initializer_list<U>>)>
    explicit optional_base(in_place_t, std::initializer_list<U> il, Args&&... args)
        : init_(true), storage_(il, std::forward<Args>(args)...) {}

    ~optional_base() { if (init_) storage_.value_.T::~T(); }
};
```

Note:

There is some complexity in this solution if you want to get an answer that supports both use in local variables in `constexpr` functions, and use at runtime with values that are nontrivially destructible. (Probably, you do want to support this, you don't want your `constexpr optional` to leak or it isn't a drop-in replacement for the regular optional.)

This is because the `constexpr` destructor must be defaulted according to language rules, but that has to be reconciled with the need to call the destructor of the generic parameter in some cases.

In Andrzej's example, this is resolved by using SFINAE and switching on `std::is_trivially_destructible` to switch to two different implementations of the `optional_base` class, one with defaulted destructor and one without. I omitted that in the above listing. If you want all the gory details I suggest you read Andrzej's code.

Comment: Wow, that's really much more code that I'd ever expected.

Comment: @james well, welcome to implementing a near language-level feature inside C++. ;)

Comment: Don't you need the destructor to be `constexpr` for this DIY optional to be usable in a constexpr context?

Comment: @emile: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45071876/why-cant-a-destructor-be-marked-constexpr

Comment: @ChrisBeck hence my comment. I checked Andrzej's optional implementation, and I see now that he conditionally inherits from a `constexpr_optional_base` with no destructor if T is trivially destructible.

I'm afraid your snippet only shows how to implement optional storage for the runtime case.

Comment: yeah I guess you are right, sorry. it's been a long time since i looked at this. i will put some kind of explanation in the comment