# Why can't a destructor be marked constexpr?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, constexpr

In C++, you can declare many things as [`constexpr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr): variables, functions (including member functions and operators), constructors, and since C++1z, also [`if` statements](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if) and [lambda expressions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda). However, declaring a [destructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/destructor) `constexpr` results in an error:

```
struct X {
    constexpr ~X() = default; // error: a destructor cannot be 'constexpr'
};
```

My questions:

1. Why can't a destructor be marked `constexpr`?
2. If I do not provide a destructor, is the implicitly generated destructor `constexpr`?
3. If I declare a defaulted destructor (`~X() = default;`), is it automatically `constexpr`?

Comment: For (1), please clarify whether you're asking about where in the standard it says a destructor cannot be constexpr; or if you are asking about the rationale for that rule

Comment: @M.M I am mainly interested where in the standard it says that a destructor cannot be constexpr, but a rationale for that rule would be also nice to know.

Comment: Is there a reason why `constexpr` would be useful on a destructor?  I can't come up with a compelling example where it would benefit a program.

Comment: An example would be attempting to subclass a struct with padding, in such a way that the padding is optimized away (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24110347). If you add a non-default dtor to the base struct (to optimize the padding away), your derived class could not be constexpr, since its dtor will not be constexpr.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Since C++20, user-defined destructors can also be `constexpr` under certain conditions.

[dcl.constexpr/3](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.constexpr#3):

> The definition of a constexpr function shall satisfy the following
> requirements:
>
> - its return type (if any) shall be a literal type;
> - each of its parameter types shall be a literal type;
> - it shall not be a coroutine ([dcl.fct.def.coroutine]);
> - if the function is a constructor or destructor, its class shall not have any
>   virtual base classes;
> - its function-body shall not enclose ([stmt.pre])
> - a goto statement,
> - an identifier label ([stmt.label]),
> - a definition of a variable of non-literal type or of static or thread
>   storage duration.

As per the [C++17 draft basic.types#10](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.types#10), a class type is a literal type only if it is:

> A possibly cv-qualified class type that has all of the following properties:
>
> (10.5.1) - it has a trivial destructor,
>
> (10.5.2) - it is either a closure type, an aggregate type, or has at
> least one constexpr constructor or constructor template (possibly
> inherited from a base class) that is not a copy or move constructor,
>
> (10.5.3) - if it is a union, at least one of its non-static data
> members is of non-volatile literal type

> (10.5.4) - if it is not
> a union, all of its non-static data members and base classes are of
> non-volatile literal types.

**Question 1: Why a destructor cannot be marked as constexpr?**

Because only trivial destructors are qualified for constexpr.
Following is the relevant section of the [draft](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.dtor#5)

> A destructor is trivial if it is not user-provided and if:
>
> (5.4) — the destructor is not virtual,
>
> (5.5) — all of the direct base classes of its class have trivial
> destructors, and
>
> (5.6) — for all of the non-static data members of its class that are
> of class type (or array thereof), each such class has a trivial
> destructor.
>
> Otherwise, the destructor is non-trivial.

**Question 2: If I do not provide a destructor, is the implicitly generated destructor constexpr?**

Yes, because implicitly generated destructor is trivial type, so it is qualified for constexpr.

**Question 3: If I declare a defaulted destructor (~X() = default;), is it automatically constexpr?**

Yes, this destructor is user-declared and implicitly-generated and thus it is qualified for constexpr.

---

I'm not able to find any direct reference that only trivial `destructors` are qualified for `constexpr` but if the destructor is not trivial then it is for sure that class type is not `cv-qualified.` So it kind of implicit as you can't define a `destructor` for `cv-qualified` class.

---

Comment: Can you please add a reference for this claim? _Because only trivial destructors are qualified for constexpr._

Comment: If you can add the feature test macro that checks the presence of this feature, it would be would be like gravy. I think it's `__cpp_constexpr_dynamic_alloc` (P0784R7), but I'm not 100% certain.

Answer (score 8):

If what you're looking for is reasoning behind the restriction, have a look at [this paper](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0784r0.md) which clearly states that **the restriction is artificial** - there is no intrinsic property of destructors that prevent them from working in constexpr contexts, and indeed **compiler implementors agree that supporting them in constexpr contexts will be trivial to implement**.

I guess the C++ standards committee originally placed the restriction in C++11 because they didn't want to deal with destructors at that time and it was easier to just rule them out entirely.

Answer (score 5):

Since C++20, a constructor may be marked `constexpr`; I don’t know if it says anywhere specifically “a destructor may be `constexpr`”, but the [draft standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/n4849.pdf) includes the following text in section 9.2.5 paragraph 5:

> The definition of a `constexpr` destructor whose function-body is not `= delete` shall additionally satisfy the
>   following requirement:
>
> - for every subobject of class type or (possibly multi-dimensional) array thereof, that class type shall
>     have a constexpr destructor.

This also now has a useful function because C++20 also allows `new` and `delete` in `constexpr` contexts, allowing things like `vector` and `string` to work at compile time without hacks (although I believe C++20 does not actually include changes to the standard library to allow for this, it is possible to implement something with the same API and behaviour as `vector` that works completely at compile time).

Comment: _Since C++20, a constructor may be marked constexpr;_  Oops. Either the _Since C++20_ or the _constructor_ was a typo. (I vote for the latter.) ;-)

Comment: Why constexpr smart pointers could not have been added in c++20 ?

Answer (score 4):

> Why a destructor cannot be marked as constexpr?

The C++11 standard is specific about use of `constexpr` for consructors and non-static member function. It does not say anything specific about destructor. One may assume that destructors are to be treated as non-static member functions.

`constexpr` can be used only for `const` member functions. Since a destructor cannot be `const` member function, it cannot be qualified as a `constexpr` member function.

> If I do not provide a destructor, is the implicitly generated destructor `constexpr`.

Since use of

```
constexpr ~X() = default;
```

is an error, it makes sense to me that the compiler generated destructor is not a `constexpr` function. I can't find anything in the standard to justify my statement. I am guessing.

> If I declare a defaulted destructor (`~X() = default;`), is it automatically `constexpr`

I think not. Once again, I can't find anything in the standard to justify my statement. I am guessing.

---

FWIW, g++ compiles and builds the following program just fine.

```
struct X {
   constexpr X(int i) : i_(i) {}
   ~X() = default;
   int i_;
};

int main()
{
   const X x(10);
}
```

Comment: "`constexpr` can be used only for `const` member functions."  This is no longer true since C++14.

Answer (score 2):

[Reference](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3597.html) say's:

> **constexpr destructors**
>
> In most cases, in order to create an object of a type T in a constant
>   expression, the destruction of T must be trivial. However, non-trivial
>   destructors are an important component of modern C++, partly due to
>   widespread usage of the RAII idiom, which is also applicable in
>   constexpr evaluations. Non-trivial destructors could be supported in
>   constant expressions, as follows:
>
> - Allow destructors to be marked as constexpr
> - Make defaulted destructors constexpr if they only invoke constexpr destructors
> - For constexpr variables, require that evaluating the destructor is a constant expression (except that the object being destroyed may be
>     modified in its own destructor
>
> However, no compelling use cases are known for such a feature, and
>   there would be a non-trivial implementation cost ensuring that
>   destructors are run at the right times.

Comment: Wouldn't a use case be the compile-time evaluation of complex math?  But I do suppose correct implementation of such a feature would be a major pain for compiler programmers and probably not worth having.

Answer (score 1):

A destructor can't be `constexpr` because `constexpr` functions can't have side effects and destructors by definition are only useful through side effects. In short, it would be useless to have a destructor that is `constexpr`.

A object cannot be `constexpr` if its destructor is non-trivial. A defaulted one, if trivial, will be considered `constexpr`

[Live](https://godbolt.org/g/g696WQ)

From [[class.dtor]](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.dtor#1.3)

> Each decl-specifier of the decl-specifier-seq of a destructor declaration (if any) shall be `friend`, `inline`, or `virtual`.

Missing from it, `constexpr`. So you could just take it as: because the standard says so<sup>TM</sup>

Comment: "destructors by definition only have side effects." is not true. It's easy to write a destructor that has no side effect.

Comment: @M.M Care to elaborate? Destructors have no arguments and returns nothing, what do you do inside its body?

Comment: Anything you like. The body could be empty, or execute some statements with no side-effects

Comment: @M.M Will you accept this rewording: *"destructors is useful only through side-effects"*

Comment: That's better although I'm not sure this goes far towards answering the question

Comment: @M.M To me, this is the only thing that answers the *why*. The standard says basically nothing about `constexpr` in the context of destructors which is why quotes here are all only indirectly related. The standard doesn't often talk about *why* it is written a certain way.

Comment: It is not true that constexpr functions can't have side effects. Check out bar here: https://godbolt.org/g/LhVGy2

Comment: Yeah unfortunately this answer doesn't make sense, see the link above.^ -1